# Get cookie used when connecting to Node

Tags: erlang

According to [documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html) there is function `erlang:set_cookie(Node, Cookie)` that *Sets the magic cookie used when connecting to Node.*

Is there a way to *Get* the magic cookie used when connecting to Node?

Comment: The magic cookie of the local node is retrieved by calling erlang:get_cookie(). from your link.

Comment: The question is not about cookie of the local node but about cookie used to connect to another node which was overrided by `set_cookie/2` call.